# Android client does not connect to PHP server

Tags: php, android, ubuntu, android-volley

An image as a string is supposed to be sent to the PHP server from android client.
And the server side code is this one
*

```
<?php
    echo "fata";
    if (isset($_POST['image'])) {
      $data = $_POST['image'];
      $name= $_POST['name'];

      $decodedImage = base64_decode($image);
      $image_file=time().rand(1111,9999);
      $name=$name.$image_file;
      $base_path='/var/www/html/CGIR/Uploads/';


      file_put_contents($base_path.$name.".jpg", $decodedImage);
      echo "wow!!!! You did it awesome man ...!!!";
       }
      echo "here";

    ?>
```

*

On the client side error was generated: timeout. So, I set the time to 5000 initially. But the client keeps trying to get connected and it doesn't connect to server. I tried using the same upload url in browser and it works. And the apache is up and running as well. I also tried disabling the firewall. But nothing seems to work.
This is the android side

```
                    //Showing the progress dialog
                    final ProgressDialog loading =ProgressDialog.show(this,"Uploading...","Please wait...",false,false);
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new     StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String s) {
                                        //Disimissing the progress dialog
                                    loading.dismiss();
                                    //Showing toast message of the response
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                        },
                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {    
                                //Dismissing the progress dialog
                                System.out.println("Fama"+volleyError);
                                loading.dismiss();

                            //Showing toast
                                  try{
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
                                catch(Exception     E){System.out.println("Exception occured"+E);}
                        }
                        }){
                        @Override
                       protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                             //Converting Bitmap to String
                            String image = getStringImage(bitmap);

                        //Getting Image Name
                            String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();

                        //Creating parameters
                            Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

                            //Adding parameters
                            params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
                            params.put(KEY_NAME, name);

                            //returning parameters
                            return params;
                    } 
                };

                //Creating a Request Queue
               RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

                //Adding request to the queue
               requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
               stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                        50,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            }
```

Comment: is it a localhost or live url

Comment: your URL working in a browser or not?

Comment: try replacing **50** to **50000** in  `setRetryPolicy`.

Comment: I think that you are using wrong IP address or URL.

Comment: @VivekMishra it is localhost

Comment: @VladMatvienko No IP adresss and URL both are correct. I tried the same link in my browser and it opened

Comment: @RahulSharma I did set it to 5000 initially but it didn't connect

Comment: you've tried in desktop browser, or in the browser of the device, you running the app on? (Android phone)

Comment: Desktop browser

Comment: try in mobile device to check if the mobile device can access the url/IP

Comment: http://10.99.13.146/CGIR/hello.php/ I got the ipadress from ifconfig under inet and CGIR is the directory in html and hello.php is the file name

Comment: In the mobile device it says : This site can't be reached. How should I fix it?

Comment: try opening this url from the device, you want your app to run on. I'm sure that your mobile device has no access to that IP since it is the local IP, and your device is not connected to that local network

Comment: `How should I fix it?` use real IP, or connect device to the same network as a PHP server

Comment: They both are connected to the same WIFI network.